# Declare object as a Class Member

Tags: c#, class, stream

Can a class object such a StreamWriter be declared in C# at the class level? I have multiple functions that don't relate to each other that need access to the same StreamWriter, but since it has to be initiated with a stream for its constructor, I don't know how to declare it outside of the functions.

Comment: A StreamWriter is just a helper class that knows how to write text (as opposed to raw binary) to a stream. You can create multiple writers on the same stream. Just remember that calling Dispose on a StreamWriter will close the underlying stream (StreamWriter.BaseStream), so make sure that management of the stream's lifetime is outside and you don't dispose the writer(s).

Comment: Post some example code that shows what you're trying to do. We can probably help you then.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no multithread issue, you can declare it outside class and initialize it inside the functions with proper stream.

However, it's a good practice to declare and initialize the stream inside each function as needed.

Comment: How do I do that? When I declare it outside of the function, I get the error "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property..."

Comment: If I declare the streamwriter inside the individual functions, I am going to have to declare my process outside of the function then so that I can do myStrmWriter = process.StandardInput; in each of the functions. The only alternative I can see would be to store my process ID globally, then sort through all proccesses, find the instance, and so on. This seems really inefficient though.

Answer (score 0):

You mean doing something like this?  Declare it as a member of your class, then initialize it in your constructor.

```
public class Foo
{
    private StreamWriter writer;

    public Foo()
    {
        writer = new StreamWriter(...);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am doing it as you listed, and have writer = new StreamWriter(minecraftProcess.StandardInput.BaseStream); in my function, but still getting an error about object reference required for writer.

Comment: Then you need to post a short but complete example that demonstrates your code problem.  You're referencing `writer` before assigning to it in your constructor.  All of us can only answer correctly given enough information.  If you are instantiating `writer` in your constructor as I have here, you shouldn't  be having problems.  As it is, this answers "how do I declare a StreamWriter at the class level", which is basically what you asked.